# What is the logic behind this C Program?

Tags: algorithm, c, logic

Here is a small piece of program (14 lines of program) which **counts the number of bits set in a number**.

Input-Output --> 0-->0(0000000), 5-->2(0000101), 7-->3(0000111)

```
int CountBits (unsigned int x)
{
  static unsigned int mask[] = { 0x55555555,
      0x33333333,
      0x0F0F0F0F,
      0x00FF00FF,
      0x0000FFFF
      } ;

      int i ;
      int shift ; /* Number of positions to shift to right*/
      for (i =0, shift =1; i < 5; i ++, shift *= 2)
              x = (x & mask[i ])+ ( ( x >> shift) & mask[i]);
      return x;
}
```

Can someone explain the algorithm used here/why this works?

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: The complete logic of the program seems alien to me. Actually, I am a beginner C programmer and that is why I am having difficulty understanding this. Please, can you tell me the whole working of the program. Thanks.

Comment: If you're a beginning programmer, just ignore this for now. Focus on learning the basics before you stress out trying to understand clever bit twiddling tricks - it'll just confuse and distract you from important things.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like the DC component of a FFT transform.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething - I believe your comment was well intentioned, but it's not terribly helpful.  All of us had to start somewhere.  Some of us chose to start with more difficult problems than others.  Bit twiddling is one of C's strengths and can be an important area to learn depending upon future interests.  It's arguable that understanding bit twiddling is one of the most basic or fundamental components of C since it provides a deep understanding of the primitives offered by the language.

Comment: As a historical note, use your favorite search engine to search for HAKMEM 169.

Comment: @OldFart -- Can you suggest me some good search engines?

Comment: I generally use Ohloh & Kruggle. Are there any good search engines besides these two?

Comment: @GlenH7 - Agree whole-heartedly with your viewpoint.  It does no good to be too myopic or exclusive when applying our _question validity filter_.

Comment: See [How to Properly Google for C](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/109420/12878) for tips on searching for information on C (difficult when the language name is a single letter).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.graphics.algorithms/ZKSegl2sr4c/QYTwoPSx30MJ), by Ian Ashdown, explains it in more detail:

> Freed's numbers are members of a sequence, where the Nth number of the
>   sequence is itself an infinite sequence from right to left of 2**N 1's
>   followed by 2**N 0's, followed 2**N 1's, and so on. The initial
>   numbers are:

```
...0101010101010101
...0011001100110011
...0000111100001111
...0000000011111111
...
```

> For a word size of 16 bits then, we have four "B-constants":

```
B[1] = 0101010101010101
B[2] = 0011001100110011
B[3] = 0000111100001111
B[4] = 0000000011111111
```

So that's what those numbers in `mask[]` are, eg. `0x55555555` is the [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of the bit pattern `1010101010101010101010101010101`.

The algorithm itself does this:

1. Interpret adjacent bits as numbers (0 or 1) and add them. The results are numbers that can be represented with two bits (ie. 0 to 3).
2. Interpret adjacent *pairs* of bits as numbers (0 to 3) and add them. The results can be represented with four bits (ie. 0 to 15).
3. Interpret adjacent *groups-of-4* bits as numbers (0 to 15) and add them. The results can be represented with eight bits (ie. 0 to 255).

...and so on, until you have a result that is as wide as however many bits you need.

I suggest that you try it on paper, by hand, with a few numbers using the binary masks above. Then you might get a feel for the algorithm being expressed by that code.